# Flutter "Unable to find git in your PATH." after installing git

Tags: linux, flutter, docker

I am using Sonarqube to have a flutter project of mine analyzed. For this to work I need to install Flutter inside the SonarScanner Docker container. So far no big deal, the container is based on an Alpine Linux. So I did the following in the container:

```
$ apk add git
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
OK: 323 MiB in 90 packages
$ git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git /usr/local/flutter
Cloning into '/usr/local/flutter'...
$ export PATH="$PATH":"/usr/local/flutter/bin:/usr/local/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"
$ echo $PATH
/opt/sonar-scanner/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/flutter/bin:/usr/local/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin
$ find / -name git
/var/git
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/git
/usr/bin/git
/usr/libexec/git-core/git
```

My analyses with Sonarqube don't bring any results, so I had a look if Flutter or Dart are running at all. I can run the command `flutter analyze` (the flutter bin is found) but flutter itself cannot find the git binary, although it is correctly located in the path as shown above.

```
$ flutter analyze
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
```

Maybe one of you has an idea where my problem is, thank you already in any case.

Comment: Rather than installing git manually in the container, you should create a new image using a Dockerfile. Otherwise git will be gone when the container exits and you run it again.

Comment: Hi, yes I know, every time the container starts it fetches git again, this might be a bit messy but I would like to use the sonarscanner container image to benefit from the updates and not my own image. Also, the whole thing runs in a pipeline, meaning the container is thrown away after every round either way.

Comment: You can base your own image on the sonarscanner image, so everything in the sonarscanner image will be available

Comment: Sounds not bad at all, maybe i'll try that, but unfortunately even if it works that doesn't explain why my way as described above fails. it's really unclear to me why it can't find the git binary.